# In vbscript how to run the bat file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, batch-processing

I am created the bat file using vbscript. And run that script But batch file is not run Please help me

```
Const ForReading=1, ForWriting=2, ForAppending=8
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oServiceManager = CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager") 
Set oDesktop = oServiceManager.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop") 
Dim aNoArgs() 
Dim oDoc, myrows,inut, s, shell 
s = 1
Set outFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Program Files\WinSCP\" & "\Build.bat", True)
outFile.Close
Set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Program Files\WinSCP\" & "\Build.bat", ForWriting, True)
outFile.WriteLine chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\winscp.exe" & chr(34) & " /console /script=page.txt"
outFile.Close
Set outFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Program Files\WinSCP\" & "\Page.txt", True)
outFile.Close
Path = InputBox ("Enter Your Path:")
inut = "file:///" & Path
Set oDoc = oDesktop.loadComponentFromURL(inut, "_blank", 0, aNoArgs) 
oDoc.CurrentController.Frame.ContainerWindow.setVisible(false) 
set oSheet = oDoc.Sheets.getByName("Sheet1") 
set oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition( 3, 2 ) 'A2
DomainName = oCell.getString() 
set oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition( 3, 3 ) 'A2
nFile = oCell.getString() 
nFile = nFile - 1
Set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Program Files\WinSCP\" & "\Page.txt", ForWriting, True)
outFile.WriteLine "option confirm off"
outFile.WriteLine "open sftp://root@" & DomainName & " -hostkey=" & chr(34) &"ssh-rsa 1024 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"& Chr(34)
outFile.WriteLine "option transfer binary"
For i = 0 To nFile
set oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition( 0, s ) 'A2
nValue = oCell.getString() 
set oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition( 1, s ) 'A2
nsValue = oCell.getString() 
outFile.WriteLine "put " & nValue & " " & nsValue
s = s+1 
Next
outFile.WriteLine "# Disconnect"
outFile.WriteLine "# close"
outFile.Close
oDoc.Close(true) 
msgbox "Done"
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.run "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\" & "\Build.bat"
set shell=nothing
```

I am created the bat file using vbscript. And run that script But batch file is not run Please help me

**Edited:**

```
Line: 49 Char: 1 Error: The system cannot find the specified Code: 80070002 Source: (nul)
```

Comment: `@Mani Kandan` please specify which error you got...?

Comment: U see this my error >>>>> Line: 49 Char: 1 Error: The system cannot find the specified Code: 80070002 Source: (nul)

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even have 49 lines.

Comment: i am removed empty line poster area. Last three line error

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work on my machine by using
**shell.run """C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Build.bat"""**
 Reason: Program Files has a space so it has to be enclosed in quotes - therefore you need 3 quotes on both ends.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`BuildPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method when constructing paths. It avoids headaches with path separators.

```
>>> Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>> WScript.Echo fso.BuildPath("C:\some\folder", "file.ext")
C:\some\folder\file.ext
>>> WScript.Echo fso.BuildPath("C:\some\folder\", "\file.ext")
C:\some\folder\file.ext
```

Also, it's pointless to concatenate string literals like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinSCP\" & "\Build.bat"
```

Just make it a single string when you don't have any variables in it anyway:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Build.bat"
```

Neither of the above is the reason for the error you're getting, though. Windows can handle duplicate path separators just fine.

The file you're trying to execute can't be found, because the path contains a space, so your code is actually trying to execute a file `C:\Program` (which doesn't exist) with an argument `Files\WinSCP\\Build.bat`.

You need to put double quotes around the path to prevent this, either by using literal double quotes (which must be doubled to escape them inside a string):

```
shell.Run """C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Build.bat"""
```

or by concatenating the string with ASCII character 34:

```
shell.Run Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Build.bat" & Chr(34)
```

It's usually helpful to put the code for creating a double-quoted string in a function:

```
Function qq(str)
  qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34)
End Function
```

and use the function like this:

```
shell.Run qq("C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Build.bat")
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this recently to create a batch file from a vbscript (for winscp!) and this is how I did it.

```
strProcessToKill = "winscp.exe"

'Sets "shell" to run a shell command
sub shell(cmd)
'Run a command as if you were running from the command line
dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run(cmd)
Set objShell = Nothing
end sub

'Creates Sync.bat, which is called at the end of the script.(This is what passes the      FTP parameters to the WinSCP Program)
SET objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Open write stream
SET outFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\RDSync\sync.bat", True)

'Write to Batch File
outFile.WriteLine "@echo off"
outFile.WriteLine "cd %programfiles%\winscp\"
outFile.WriteLine "start /b winscp.exe /log=""C:\RDSync\logs\!M-!D-!Y@!T.xml""     /xmlgroups /command ""open ftp://username:password@ftp.foo.com"" ""synchronize local -delete -criteria=size" & + " " + """""" + RDfolder + """""" + " " + "/"
outFile.WriteLine "exit"

'Close Write Stream
outFile.Close

'Allows script to access Running Processes"
SET objWMIService = GETOBJECT("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

'set variable to Winscp Process Instance
SET colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & strProcessToKill & "'")

'Checks to see if an instance of WinSCP.exe is running, and if it is, it closes it.   This will loop to close multiple processes
count = 0
FOR EACH objProcess in colProcess
objProcess.Terminate()
count = count + 1

Next

'Runs the batch file from a silent shell command
shell "C:\RDSync\sync.bat"
```

In the above example, the variable "RDfolder" is c:\users\username\documents\synced files

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Try shell.run "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Build.bat" 
According to your code you are trying to run C:\Program Files\WinSCP\\Build.bat 
Note the double \\ when you concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting one additional backslash every time you name the files in all cases. For example, this line:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinSCP\" & "\Build.bat"
```

produce:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinSCP\\Build.bat"
```

If after correcting this error *in all instances* still not works, insert `/C` parameter in the execution of Batch file this way:

```
shell.run "/C C:\Program Files\WinSCP\" & "Build.bat"
```

Comment: Confirm that the `Build.bat` file is correctly created in the right place after the vbs program ends...

Comment: check i am created bat file using vbs. bat in right place. manually run that bat file its run. and also save last three line in vbscript command its work. Please help

Comment: Its urgent please help me

Comment: The double path separator doesn't cause any problems. Windows can handle that just fine. And trying to run `/c something` will raise an error, because there's nothing the option would apply to. You need `%COMSPEC% /c ...` or `cmd /c ...` for this to work.